# Is timezone taken into account when storing Instant to DB

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, h2, java-time

I use hibernate (5.0.11) to write to a H2 and a Postgresql DB.
I want my domain objects to contain Java 8 `Instant` - these objects just reflect an instant in time (no notion of date, time, offset or zone). Basically this corresponds to the millis (or nanos) since epoch.

I use the `hibernate-java8` package which maps `Instant` to a TIMESTAMP type in the DB.

The H2 doc [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#timestamp_type) says that it stores the TIMESTAMP as a "BCD-encoded date, and nano-seconds since midnight."

Now I a bit afraid that I am introducing a timezone somewhere - Instant needs no zone, but to convert it to this date-nanos representation, there is a zone somewhere (hopefully UTC).

Must I do anything to be sure that this is converted with UTC? Do I need to set a timezone - on hibernate? on JDBC? on the JVM?

Should I rather store millis since epoch in a BIGINT to be robust?

If it works for H2, will it work correctly for Postgresql?

Comment: Actually, you are incorrect about `Instant`. That class *does* have a notion of time zone: UTC. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution in nanoseconds.  The `LocalDateTime` class in contrast has no notion of offset-from-UTC nor time zone. A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment on the timeline.

Comment: @Philipp Instant and Timestamp are similar: they refer to the number of miilis since the epoch and don't "hold" a time zone (everything is in UTC). So you should be fine.

Comment: Actually I did a few tests an in fact the value that is written to the DB is in the timezone of the JVM. As long you write an read in the same timezone, this is transparent. Problem arise of you read from a different timezone - then you get different instants for the same DB value

Comment: I can not answer as this question is related to hibernate. However I can answer on the Posgresql & h2 time insertion. In our side we do not rely on TIMESTAMP type as @Philipp says it use somewhere the local timezone. We translate it into a ISO 8601 time string (http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#date_time) using this method https://github.com/Ifsttar/NoiseCapture/blob/0.4.6/onomap-geoserver/geoserver/src/main/groovy/org/noise_planet/noisecapturegs/nc_parse.groovy#L76